# Объединении трех таблиц в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

У меня есть три таблицы, которые я хочу объединить. Для этого я написал запрос, но проблема в том, что я частично достиг своей цели. Я хочу сделать таблицу со статусом заполнения! Для этого мне нужно, чтобы данные из таблицы SEC_OBJECTS_FILLING были постоянными, а данные из других таблиц - самыми последними!

Я смоделировал [скрипт](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc936dd6739e6d9418ae465dcbbd2a5e) и у меня есть результат там. Но я хочу иметь такой результат.

```
NAME_OBJ  DATA_AREA   SEALS  DATA        NAME_UR  SEAL_NUMBER  NAME_USR  DATA_UNPLUG
--------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------- ----------- ---------- -----------
OBJ1      DATA_AREA1  Yes     2019-11-13  ADMIN    A14602631    
OBJ2      DATA_AREA2  Yes     2019-11-13  ANDRII   A14602632
OBJ3      DATA_AREA1  No      2019-11-13  ADMIN    A14602638    ADMIN     2019-11-13 
OBJ4      DATA_AREA1  No
```

То есть я хочу видеть только последние действия с моим объектом, а не всю историю. (Я запечатал объекты (1,2,3,) и потом розпечатал объекты (1,2,3), но затем снова запечатал объекты (1,2). Объект 4 я не запечатал!) Надеюсь, вы понимаете.

Буду признателен за вашу помощь!

Comment: У тебя нет никаких "сначала" и "потом". Все действия датированы одной и той же датой - посему в принципе невозможно определить, что было раньше и что позже. Задача не решается на таких данных.

Comment: @Akina https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc936dd6739e6d9418ae465dcbbd2a5e  , я все исправил ! по этой ссылке данные максимально приближены к реальным)

Comment: А ничего не поменялось. Как была ДАТА, так и осталась. Если в поле с типом даты пытаться записывать дату-время. то ошибки, конечно, не возникнет - но и в поле ляжет только компонент даты, а время тихо похерится. А ещё расскажи-ка... судя по `ORDER BY sos.SEAL_NUMBER` это поле имеет какое-то назначение, а сортировка по нему соответственно какой-то смысл - какой? и почему RANK(), а, не, скажем, ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: Я использовал этот способ, того что он подвел меня ближе к мои цели! Я просто хочу обеднаты таблицы таким способом, чтобы мои обектов постоянными, а данные из второй таблицы подтягивались последние по дате. То есть меня интересует только когда в последний был запломбирован мой обектов а, а данные между 2 и 3 таблицами подтягиваются по номеру пломбирования!

Comment: И я никак не могу вириты эту проблему. Но в таблице есть точно дата, оно просто не видображаться в ответе! Или нет ???

Comment: *в таблице есть точно дата* Вот именно что дата. Без времени. *а данные из второй таблицы подтягивались последние по дате* А раз дата одна и та же, то не определить, какая запись последняя.

Comment: но смотрите, объект 1-я опломбировывал последний раз 06.12.2019, а оно подтянуло 04.12!

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica Я лично вижу, что в fiddle выводится только дата. И мне пофиг, чья это проблема - типа данных, использованной функции to_date(), или чего-то ещё - но результат один, в таблице компоненты времени НЕТ.

Comment: [TO_DATE() function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) - внимательнейшим образом прочитайте описание. Особенно насчёт второго параметра.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101967/discussion-between---and-akina).